# Database schema for Partners

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

We have an application to manage company, teams, branches,employee etc and have different tables for that. Now we have a requirement that we have to give access of same system to our technology partners so that they can also do the same thing which we are doing. But at the same time we need to supervise these partners in our system.

So in terms of DB schema what will be the best way to manage them:

1)To duplicate the entire schema for partners, and for that we have to duplicate around 50-60 tables and many more in future as system will grows.

2)To create some flag in each table which will tell it is internal or external entity.

Please suggest if anyone has any experience.

Comment: When you say you need "that we have to give access of same system to our technology partners" do you mean that they will access the same data or they will insert their own set of data in the system? For example will they have their own set of company, teams, branches employees or they are just going to access your data.

Comment: @phonetic_man: Thanks for taking interest in my problem, Yes partners will insert their own data in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following points before finalizing any of the approaches.

**Do you want a holistic view of the data**

By this I mean that do you want to view the data your partner creates and which you create in a single report / form. If the answer is yes then it would make sense to store the database in the same set of tables and differentiate them based on some set of columns.

**Is your application functionality going to vary significantly**

If the answer to this question is NO then it would make sense to keep the data in the same set of tables. This way any changes you do to your system will automatically reflect to all the users and you won't have to replicate your code bits across schemas / databases.

**Are you and your partner going to use the  same master / reference data**

If the answer to this question is yes then again it makes sense to use the same set of tables since you will do away with unnecessary redundant data.

**Implementation**

Rather than creating a flag I would recommend creating a master table known as user_master. The key of this table should be made available in every transaction table. This way if you want to include a second partner down the line you can make a new entry in your user_master table and make necessary modifications to your application code. Your application code should manage the security. Needless to say that you need to implement as much security as possible at the database level too.

**Other Suggestions**

- To physical separate data of these entities you can either implement
  partitioning or sharding depending upon the db you are using.
- Perform thorough regression testing and check that your data is not
  visible in partner reports or forms. Also, check that partner is not
  able to update or insert your data.
- Since the data in your system will increase significantly it would
  make sense to performance test your reports, forms and programs.
- If you are using indexes then you will need to revisit those since
  your where conditions would change.
- Also, revisit your keys and relationships.

Comment: I am already having a user table which saves all types of users internal employees, internal customers.

The problem now we have is that partner's company will come under some of our company and our internal team will manage these partners, teams are meant to manage branches and partners for our internal system  but for partners only branches. So if we use the same Company and Team tables for our internal and partners then we have to add some extra columns to make differentiate between internal and partner.

 Can you suggest how to do this in a good way.

Comment: I assume your user table stores one record for each partner. If this is the case then add a column to the user table to signify internal or external. If this is not the purpose of you user table then create a different table named companies or something similar which will contain the list of partners as well as your main company. Now the key from this table can be floated in all transaction tables as well as your user table. As far as data access security is concerned you will have to code it in the application. What database are you using?

Comment: I am doing the same which you suggested, I am using SQL Server 2014 enterprise edition.

Thanks for giving so clear explanation and understanding the problem exactly. You really make my day :-)

Comment: Great, I am glad that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

None of your asked suggestion is advisable. You need to follow given guideline to secure your whole system and audit your technology partner as well.

[1]You should create a module on Admin side which will show you existing tables as well table which will be added in future.

[2]Create user for your technology partner and provide permission on those objects.

[3]Keep one audit-trail table, and insert entry of user name/IP etc.in it. So you will have complete tracking of activity carried out by your technology partner.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem but my main concern is to how to reuse the existing database schema to accommodate the technology partner and supervise them at the same time.

By reuse I mean all tables which are for us and our customers.

Comment: You don't need to reuse schema. Just create one table for Audit Trail purpose.Use same schema.Create module the way I suggested and you should be fine